Only change cart item subtotal, but not displayed item price in WooCommerce
I have been stick on this problem for a while and I can't seem to figure out how to change the line item subtotal of a line item in woocommerce.
You see, I am making a rental site and while choosing the dates and calculating the price on the previous page, you also calculate your delivery fee if you want it delivered (based on distance).
I have the delivery fee showing up in the cart as line-item data as such:

And as you can see, the total price of the rental period is $900.00. I want to add the delivery fee to the total, and I try:
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_delivery_cart_item_price', 20, 1 );
function set_delivery_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( isset($cart_item['pr_field'])  && ! empty($cart_item['pr_field']) ) {
            $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
            $price = $price + $cart_item['pr_field'];
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price );
        }
    }
}

But it ends up changing the line item totals to:

And I would like for the total underneath the product name to remain 900.00, while the subtotal increases (The 900 underneath TOTAL). I have tried $cart_item['line_subtotal'] = $price; and $cart_item['line_total'] = $price; but even though when I print the arrays I can see those values change, it does nothing in the cart.
Is there a way to add the line item data values to the subtotal price of the line item?
Thank you!

I believe more information is needed as I have to assume certain things, but wanted to provide a possible root cause.  It appears that you are likely leveraging the same value (in this case price) for both fields. When the value is updated, both fields are updated as they reference the same variable. This is an assumption at this point, but if you have access to the and could provide the UI code, we could see what values are being leveraged and how you are triggering the updates (including passing of variables)

Try to add the following to keep cart item (product) price unchanged:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_cart_item_price_html', 2000, 2 );
function display_cart_item_price_html( $price_html, $cart_item ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['pr_field'])  && ! empty($cart_item['pr_field']) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? : $cart_item['product_id']);

        if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $price = wc_get_price_including_tax($product);
        } else {
            $price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product);
        }
        return wc_price( $price );
    }
    return $price_html;
}

It should work.
